# How to remove second ip address from a vlan interface on a switch?

Tags: networking, cisco, switch, dell-powerconnect

I am using ssh to remotely connect to a Dell PowerConnect switch (Dell uses the same commands as Cisco). I need to change the ip address of vlan 1 from 192.x.x.x to 10.x.x.x. I am able to add the new address of 10.x.x.x by:

```
console(config-if)# ip address 10.x.x.x 255.x.x.x
```

Now vlan 1 will reply from both 10.x.x.x and 192.x.x.x . How do I then remove the existing 192.x.x.x from that interface?

Comment: Dell and Cisco switches have *similar* commands, but they diverge quite a lot once you start configuring spanning-tree and I am sure some other things too.  Would be great if Dell took the trouble of publishing a cheat sheet to translate between the two.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's been a while since I've worked on Cisco gear, so this may be incorrect, but give this a try:

```
> no ip address 192.x.x.x 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: That looks correct to me and it's only been two days since I last removed an IP address from a Cisco device.

Comment: So, it appears not all the commands are the same. 'no ip address 192.x.x.x 255.255.255.0' returns "Wrong number of parameters or invalid range, size or characters entered." And 'no ip address 192.x.x.x' removes both ips

Comment: Then try `no ip address 192.x.x.x`.

Comment: On Dell PowerConnect switches, When you aren't sure how a command works, try typing it followed by ? which will then show you the possible options.  You can keep typing at ? at the end of the command to see further options.  If you see <cr> it means you don't have to add any other commands.

Answer (score 1):

`(config-if)no ip address 192.x.x.x 255.x.x.x`

Will remove the IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

In the global config mode run:

`int vlan 1`

followed by

`no ip address`

And this should do the job.This wud delete all the ip addresses on the vlan,Then you can give it the ip address u want over again